# HTML5 video in native iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, html5-video

I want to build native iOS and Android apps that play video, do I use HTML5 video in the WebView or are there more native UIs for video playback in native mode?

Are there any limitations - autoplay, fullscreen, fallback to the native player - if I use the HTML5 player in WebView?

Thanks